# Where I can find all the questions I protected?

Tags: feature-request, support, protected-questions

During the past SPAM wave on Ask Ubuntu, I was forced to protect several questions using my 15k privilege; now I'm looking for them to unprotect them now that the SPAM is gone.

Where is a list of all questions I protected?

I'm using both support and feature-request tag, if such doesn't exist so it could be created.

Comment: Errr, that doesn't really sound like a useful feature. Protection is not *meant* to be used as a temporary solution to stop a spam wave, and outside of that there's not really any reason that you'd need to find that list.

Comment: The conditions that warrant protecting a question (i.e. it is a spam magnet) do not disappear after the spam answers are removed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey they are when the SPAM is slandering OP or impersonating mods, etc.

Comment: @animuson (see above comment)

Comment: Sounds like you have a larger problem than question protection.

Comment: @RobertHarvey had... or will have, who knows.

Comment: @animuson - The fact that there currently is no way (even for moderators) to see a history of what questions a user has protected is problematic, though. We recently had a user flagged who was going around and protecting every question they saw, several of which didn't need it. I had no way of tracing this to even see which questions had been protected, and if the protection needed to be removed. We have histories for every other non-voting action by a user, why not this?